# Difference between fabric-orderer/fabric-peer and fabric-ca-orderer/fabric-ca-peer images

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Please tell me what is the difference between the fabric-orderer/fabric-peer and fabric-ca-orderer/fabric-ca-peer images. One difference I found was that fabric-ca-* images contains fabric-ca-client.

Also, which of these two sets would be carried forward in future releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your development or service environment with "fabric-ca-*" if you decide to use "FABRIC CA" for issuing certificates. If not, using OpenSSL or other CA tools for, you can use fabric-orderer, fabric-peer and ...

A typical thing fabric-ca do is automatically generate and store their own root ca or intermediate ca certificate by its configuration (e.g., fabric-ca-server-config.yaml) at the time of fabric-ca-server starting (initializing).

Comment: So we can use either "fabric-ca-orderer/peer" or "fabric-orderer/peer" on production, is it true?

Comment: No. The "fabric-ca-*" images are for hosting the Fabric CA servers, whereas "fabric-orderer" and "fabric-peer" are the images for orderers and peers respectively. You would use both if you want to use CA servers to issue certificates, and only "fabric-orderer" and "fabric-peer" if you want to use some other mechanism for issuing certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this question out of the desire to create fabric-ca-* containers for fabric 1.3, they are very nice for abandoning cryptogen.  My search led me to [FABC-722](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABC-722) and a commentor had a nice link to the [gerrit](https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/26401/). I landed up being able to create 1.3 versions simply by cloning [fabric-ca](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca) and running make docker-all.  After inspecting it with my poor knowledge of make i found it linked to various Dockerfile.in's in the [images](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/tree/release-1.3/images) folder.  The [fabric-ca-orderer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/release-1.3/images/fabric-ca-orderer/Dockerfile.in) for example runs this.

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
FROM _NS_/fabric-orderer:_FABRIC_TAG_
COPY payload/fabric-ca-client /usr/local/bin
ARG FABRIC_CA_DYNAMIC_LINK=false
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/fabric-ca-client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat && rm -rf /var/cache/apt

# libraries needed when image is built dynamically
RUN if [ "$FABRIC_CA_DYNAMIC_LINK" = "true" ]; then apt-get install -y libltdl-dev; fi
```

I hope this at least leads you to the answer your seeking